# How to test input values using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on one input application where i need to test input values that accepts single, multiple and even a range of numbers .

```
Eg inputs : 70,900,80-20 // should return true as all are valid
as,@123 // should return false as it is not valid digit
12-123-12123-123123 // should also return false
```

I am trying to use this in regex. I have tried this.

```
/^[\d,\-{1}]+/
```

I am not able to test using this regex. Let me know where i am doing wrong

Comment: The rule regarding hyphens is that there can only be one but it can be followed by any number of integers? `^\d+(-?\d+)?$`

Comment: Which characters are valid? or simply put more examples.

Comment: @hungerstar Only one hyphen can be add . It just simple like number range for eg : 8-20 but this should not be valid 8-20-80

Comment: @mrReiha only single hyphen and commas are allowed.

Comment: [take a look at this](https://regex101.com/r/XhzgFo/1) -> `/^\d+-?\d*$/`

Comment: @mrReiha what if it has multiple values like this 12,123.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regular expression should work for you:

```
/^\d+(-\d+)?(,\d+(-\d+)?)*$/
```

Explanation:

- `^` means to start at the beginning of the string, to reject strings with extra stuff at the beginning
- `\d+(-\d+)?` accepts a number optionally followed by a hyphen and another number:

  - `\d+` means one or more digits
  - `-\d+` means hyphen plus one or more digits
  - `(...)?` means the pattern inside the parentheses is optional
- `(,...)*` accepts 0 or more instances of comma followed by the same pattern as above
- `$` says to match until the end of the string, to reject strings with extra stuff at the end

Comment: It works like charm. Can you explain this regex more. I didnt understand.

Comment: Just added more details to the explanation. Is it clear enough now? I can augment more if needed.

Comment: Thanks understood

Answer (score 2):

`/^\d+(-\d+)?(,\d+(-\d+)?)*$/`

```js
const input = document.querySelector( 'input' );
const msg   = document.querySelector( '.msg' );
const regex = /^\d+(-\d+)?(,\d+(-\d+)?)*$/;

input.addEventListener( 'keyup', function ( e ) {
  const str = regex.test( this.value ) ? 'Match!' : 'No Match';
  msg.textContent = str;
} );
```

```html
<input type="text" name="numbers">
<div class="msg"></div>
```

Comment: Did not realize commas need to be included, updating.

Comment: its not satisfying even base condition. If i have multiple values eg : 1,12 . it is not matching.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma did you read my comment? You should also clarify that commas must be included. It's not obvious.

Comment: Nice code around the RE. I'd suggest removing `?` after `-` since it's superfluous, but it also already works as is.

Comment: @joanis thanks, I do what I can with regex as I'm no pro.